# Why is jQuery supported register button not responding?

Tags: python, jquery, html, flask

I am in the midst of building a website with the Flask framework. It of course contains users and therefore also a register site and a login site. But after adding two extra fields to the register site and bettering other parts of the code, it doesn't work anymore.

I naturally expected to see an error message in my console hosting the site locally, but that is unfortunately not the case.

Now, I've tried to remove the two extra fields, but it seems like that is not the issue.

*What is the issue with my code, and how do I fix it to make the register function work again?*

**The register site:**
Here at the register section, nothing happens when pressing the button.
[image: Here at the register section, nothing happens when pressing the button]

**The login site:**
However, here at the login section, it reacts and displays feedback when pressing the button. It works perfectly fine.
[image: However, here at the login section, it reacts and displays feedback when pressing the button]

**This is the jQuery that is supposed to make both the login function and the register function of the website work:**

```
function message(status, shake=false, id="") {
  if (shake) {
    $("#"+id).effect("shake", {direction: "right", times: 2, distance: 8}, 250);
  } 
  document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = status;
  $("#feedback").show().delay(2000).fadeOut();
}

 $(document).on("click", "#register-button", function() {
   console.log("REGISTER");
    $.post({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/register",
      data: {"username": $("#register-username").val(),
             "email": $("#register-mail").val(),
             "password": $("#register-pass").val()},
      success(response) {
        var status = JSON.parse(response)["status"];
        if (status === "Successfully registered") { location.reload(); }
        else{message(status, true, "register-box");}


      }});
  });

    $(document).on("click", "#login-button", function() {
      console.log("LOGIN");
    $.post({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/login",
      data: {"username": $("#login-username").val(), 
             "password": $("#login-pass").val()},
      success(response) {
          var status = JSON.parse(response)["status"];
          if (status === "Successfully logged in") { location.reload(); }
          else{message(status, true, "login-box");}


    }});
  });
```

**These are the routes:**

```
# ======== Routing =========================================================== #
# -------- Login ------------------------------------------------------------- #
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        next_page = request.args.get("next")
        if not next_page or url_parse(next_page).netloc != "":
            next_page = url_for("home")
        return redirect(next_page)
    form = LoginForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        if not username or not password:
            print("Both fields required")
            return json.dumps({'status': 'Both fields required'})
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
        if user is None or not user.check_password(password):
            print("Invalid username or password")
            return json.dumps({'status': 'Invalid username or password'})
        login_user(user, remember=True)
        print("Successfully logged in")
        return json.dumps({'status': 'Successfully logged in'})
    return render_template("login.html", title="Login", form=form)

# -------- Register Page ---------------------------------------------------------- #
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():

    print(current_user.is_authenticated)
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("OPRET BRUGER")
        name = request.form['name']
        location = request.form["location"]
        username = request.form["username"]
        email = request.form["email"]
        password = request.form['password']

        if not name or not location or not username or not email or not password:
            print("All fields required")
            return json.dumps({'status': 'All fields required'})

        if not User.query.filter_by(username=username).first() is None:
            print("Username taken")
            return json.dumps({'status': 'Username taken'})

        if not re.match(r"[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+", email):
            print("Invalid email")
            return json.dumps({'status': 'Invalid email'})

        location = locator.geocode(location)
        if not location:
            print("Non-valid location")
            return json.dumps({'status': 'Non-valid location'})

        user = User(name=name, location=location, username=username, email=email)
        user.set_password(password)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        login_user(user, remember=True)
        print("Successfully registered")
        return json.dumps({'status': 'Successfully registered'})

    return render_template("register.html", title="Register", form=form)
```

**This is the template for the register site:**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block body %}
<section class="hero is-white is-medium">
  <nav class="navbar is-transparent">
    <div class="navbar-brand">
      <a class="navbar-item" href="/">
        <h6 href="/" class="subtitle"><strong>Start</strong></h6>
      </a>
      <div id="navbar-burger-id" class="navbar-burger burger" data-target="navbar-menu-id">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar-menu-id" class="navbar-menu">
      <div class="navbar-end"></div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</section>
<title>Start</title>
<section class="hero is-primary is-bold is-medium">
  <div class="hero-body">
    <div class="container has-text-centered">
      <div class="columns">
        <div class="column is-auto">
          <br>
          <p class="title is-2">Start</p>
          <p class="subtitle is-4"><i>Connecting the bright minds of our world</i></p>     
        </div>
        <div class="column is-auto">
          <div id="register-box" class="register-box">
            <div class="signup-area">
              <p class="title">Opret bruger</p>
              <p> Allerede i besiddelse af en bruger?
              <a href="/login"><b>Log ind</b></a></p>
              <br>

              <div class="field">
                <p class="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
                  <input id="register-name" class="input is-success" type="text" placeholder="Navn">
                  <span class="icon is-small is-left">
                    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                  </span>
                  <span class="icon is-small is-right">
                    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                  </span>
                </p>
              </div>

              <div class="field">
                <p class="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
                  <input id="register-location" class="input" type="location" placeholder="Lokation">
                  <span class="icon is-small is-left">
                    <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
                  </span>
                  <span class="icon is-small is-right">
                    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                  </span>
                </p>
              </div>

              <br>

            <div class="field">
                <p class="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
                  <input id="register-username" class="input is-success" type="text" placeholder="Brugernavn">
                  <span class="icon is-small is-left">
                    <i class="fa fa-id-card"></i>
                  </span>
                  <span class="icon is-small is-right">
                    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                  </span>
                </p>
              </div>

              <div class="field">
                <p class="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
                  <input id="register-mail" class="input is-success" type="text" placeholder="Email">
                  <span class="icon is-small is-left">
                    <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                  </span>
                  <span class="icon is-small is-right">
                    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                  </span>
                </p>
              </div>

              <div class="field">
                <p class="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
                  <input id="register-pass" class="input" type="password" placeholder="Adgangskode">
                  <span class="icon is-small is-left">
                    <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                  </span>
                  <span class="icon is-small is-right">
                    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                  </span>
                </p>
              </div>
              <br>
              <a id="register-button" class="form-button button is-primary is-inverted is-outlined">Opret bruger</a>
              <br>
              <br>
              <i><a id="feedback" class="feedback"></a></i>
              <br>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
</section>

{% include "footer.html" %}
{% endblock %}
{% block scripts %}
<script src="../static/js/auth.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

**And this is the template for the login site:**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block body %}
<section class="hero is-white is-medium">
  <nav class="navbar is-transparent">
    <div class="navbar-brand">
      <a class="navbar-item" href="/">
        <h6 href="/" class="subtitle"><strong>Start</strong></h6>
      </a>
      <div id="navbar-burger-id" class="navbar-burger burger" data-target="navbar-menu-id">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar-menu-id" class="navbar-menu">
      <div class="navbar-end"></div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</section>
<title>Start</title>
<section class="hero is-primary is-bold is-medium">
  <div class="hero-body">
    <div class="container has-text-centered">
      <div class="columns">
        <div class="column is-auto">
          <br>
          <p class="title is-2">Start</p>
          <p class="subtitle is-4"><i>Connecting the bright minds of our world</i></p>         
        </div>
        <div class="column is-auto">
          <div id="login-box" class="login-box">
            <div class="signup-area">
              <p class="title">Log ind</p>
              <p> Ikke registreret?
              <a href="/register"><b>Opret bruger</b></a></p>
              <br>

              <div class="field">
                <p class="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
                  <input id="login-username" class="input is-success" type="text" placeholder="Brugernavn">
                  <span class="icon is-small is-left">
                    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                  </span>
                  <span class="icon is-small is-right">
                    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                  </span>
                </p>
              </div>

              <div class="field">
                <p class="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
                  <input id="login-pass" class="input" type="password" placeholder="Adgangskode">
                  <span class="icon is-small is-left">
                    <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                  </span>
                  <span class="icon is-small is-right">
                    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                  </span>
                </p>
              </div>

              <br>
              <a id="login-button" class="form-button button is-primary is-inverted is-outlined">Log ind</a>
              <br>
              <br>
              <i><a id="feedback" class="feedback"></a></i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
</section>
{% include "footer.html" %}
{% endblock %}
{% block scripts %}
<script src="../static/js/auth.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

PS

I hope that you will be able to answer my question. Please comment if I haven't provided enough info etc.

Have a nice weekend!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just edited the jQuery to this:

```
function message(status, shake=false, id="") {
  if (shake) {
    $("#"+id).effect("shake", {direction: "right", times: 2, distance: 8}, 250);
  } 
  document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = status;
  $("#feedback").show().delay(2000).fadeOut();
}

 $(document).on("click", "#register-button", function() {
   console.log("REGISTER");
    $.post({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/register",
      data: {"name": $("#register-name").val(),
             "location": $("#register-location").val(),
             "username": $("#register-username").val(),
             "email": $("#register-mail").val(),
             "password": $("#register-pass").val()},
      success(response) {
        var status = JSON.parse(response)["status"];
        if (status === "Successfully registered") { location.reload(); }
        else{message(status, true, "register-box");}


      }});
  });

    $(document).on("click", "#login-button", function() {
      console.log("LOGIN");
    $.post({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/login",
      data: {"username": $("#login-username").val(), 
             "password": $("#login-pass").val()},
      success(response) {
          var status = JSON.parse(response)["status"];
          if (status === "Successfully logged in") { location.reload(); }
          else{message(status, true, "login-box");}


    }});
  });
```

Now it works..